# How to increase the visibility of my academia question and get more responses?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I made a mistake in my thesis and posted a question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46938/what-should-i-do-if-i-discover-an-erratum-in-the-title-of-my-ms-thesis-after-sub), I was expecting to get several (considerable) answers; but unfortunately, I only received two, therefore I invite all academia users to visit that question and let me know what is the pitfalls about it, is it because my reputation is low, it is related to wording the question itself, or it is silly. I found some other simple questions on other sites [for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae?newsletter=1&nlcode=432387%7C66c5) received good responses. Sometimes your question is related to some particular (technical) problem and there might be several ways to solve that problem, in such case it doesn't matter if you get only one answer since I'll solve your problem. On other hands, some problems are opinion-based ( as [mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46938/what-should-i-do-if-i-discover-an-erratum-in-the-title-of-my-ms-thesis-after-sub) I guess), in such a case one will really be eager to receive more answers.??

Answer (score 3):

Your question has not received a lot of views (currently onIy 172). My guess is people did not find the titular question exciting and therefore did not look at it. I don't think it has anything to do with your reputation or the way you asked the question. While the question is a good fit for our site, I am not sure it is particularly interesting.

Once you have more reputation, you can offer a bounty to call attention to your question. I have offered a bounty, but I am not sure how much it will help. In addition to bounties, talking about the question in meta or chat can also help.

Comment: We shouldn't thanks in comments, but it looks I have to so, because your bounty offering which will end tomorrow helps and make sense. I'm grateful for you.